# The music app can't scan the audio file in the OTG USB stick

Tags: android, android-music-player

In Android R, I can't detect the audio files in OTG of USB stick in YT music and other music apps, but I can find them in the file explorer. How can I modify them so that the music app can detect them?

Comment: What is the reason you cannot detect them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modify file device/sprd/mpool/module/partition/msoc/sharkl5Pro/fstab

`/devices/platform/soc/soc:aon/5fff0000.usb/musb-hdrc.*.auto/usb*      auto       vfat defaults voldmanaged=usbdisk:auto`

to

`/devices/platform/soc/soc:aon/5fff0000.usb/musb-hdrc.*.auto/usb*      auto       vfat defaults voldmanaged=usbdisk:auto,encryptable=userdata`

it works